# summarizing a variable number of columns

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have a spark data frame (in the context of R and sparklyr) with three columns, id, x and y. if i want to summarize by column, i can do it with

```
df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(x=sum(x),y=sum(y))
```

Now suppose that i receive now a data frame with a variable number of columns. besides id, all the other columns are doubles and i need to summarize them as before. Of course I could get the column names, iterate summarizing each one and joining the results, but it looks ugly. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can try `dplyr::summarise_all`. The `summarise_all` will apply desired function on all column excepct the one(s) which has been used in `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_all(sum)
```

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

Would `summarise_if` work?

`df <- df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`